# Trying to install mongo-php-adater for mongodb use with symfony4 issue

Tags: mongodb, symfony4, php-mongodb

I am trying to install mongo-php-adapter to use mongoDB with Symfony 4, but I have the following problem:

**Problem 1
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.6 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.5 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.4 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter ^1.1 -> satisfiable by alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6].
 
  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.**

I installed php-mongo and put extension=mongodb.so in the php.ini file but it doesn't change anything on the contrary it says it can't find the mongodb.so file.

I also installed mongodb with pecl but still the same problem.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Are you sure about the `mongo` extenstion you installed ? (https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) Can you see the mongo extension when you run `php --ini` or `php -i` ?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, I installed mongodb-1.60alpha the latest version, and when I add extension=mongodb I get this error : **PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/mongodb.so (/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60)), /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/mongodb.so.so (/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/mongodb.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file
**

Comment: you have this error when you run a cli command ? did you add the `extension=mongodb` in the php cli ini too ?

Comment: This occurs when I run `composer require alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter`  and yes I added the `extension=mongodb` in `php.ini` thanks

Comment: I just noticed , what you mean by php cli ini ? and where I can find it, I use Xampp. Thanks

Comment: I don't really know on xampp, but usually php use one php.ini fro cli purposes and one for "web" purposes. Try searching all `*.ini` files ? Make sure to restart your web server on xamp  (by memory, there is a GUI to do that) onece you're done editing `ini` files.

Comment: Finally it works, the problem was due to libstdc++ , I follow these steps to solve it : `mv -vf libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old`, 
`ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ./libstdc++.so.6`  and restart xampp,    Thanks a lot @Etshy